# How to select table for sql query without knowing the table name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dayofweek

I am using Visual Studio 2010. Web site with a SQL Server database. My database tables are named after the days of the week (ie. `mon`, `tue`, etc..) I want to use the current day (ie. `DateTime.Now.DayofWeek`) from a web form to determine the correct table to use, possibly through the `SqlDataSource` tool.

For example:

```
'Finds current day
 Dim Day As String
    Day = CStr(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
    lblSystemDateTime.Text = Day
    If lblSystemDateTime.Text = "1" Then
        lblDayName.Text = "mon"
    ElseIf lblSystemDateTime.Text = "2" Then
        lblDayName.Text = "tue"
```

If the current day is monday I want to be able to use code like I have above to select my database table named "mon". The sqldatasource requires the table name for it's wizard, therfore I have tried to use the custom sql statement builder to create my own workaround.

Comment: Why do you have a different table for each day of the week?  This seems to be an, ummm, unusual and disruptive design choice.  Even if you can't combine them physically, maybe create a view to combine them, then query that view?  `CREATE VIEW allDates AS SELECT 1 AS date_id, * FROM mon UNION ALL SELECT 2 as date_id FROM tue UNION ALL SELECT 3 as date_id FROM wed .......` plus the final query of `SELECT * FROM allDates WHERE date_id = 2` for tuesday's data.

Comment: DayOfTheWeek should probably be an attribute on a single table for all day records. When you select records just include the day value in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Check out the Choose() function.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if want to keep table names based on the day of the week.  Pass the table name that is derived to stored procedure and dynamically build the SQL Stmt in the stored procedure and execute it.

```
     declare @vTableName varchar(50)  = '[GuestBook].[dbo] [GuestBookEntries]'  /***This variable can be passed to a procedure that dynamically builds SQL stmt  **/
     declare @ssql nvarchar(100)

     set @ssql = 'SELECT TOP 1000 [Id] ,[Name] ,[Message] ,[DateAdded] FROM ' + @vTableName


     execute sp_executesql @ssql
```